# Global variables in Laravel Blade template

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I hope to define global variable in a separate file and then inject in wherever I want, so for Laravel 4 + Blade, I did this.

Top file    example.blade.php:

```
@include('head')    
@include('body')
```

head.blade.php

```
$STYLE_PATH_CSS="styleFolder/foundation/css" 
$STYLE_PATH_JS="styleFolder/foundation/js" 
$STYLE_PATH_JS_VENDOR="styleFolder/foundation/js/vendor"
<link rel="stylesheet" href=" <?php echo $STYLE_PATH_CSS ?>/normalize.css ">
<link rel="stylesheet" href=" <?php echo $STYLE_PATH_CSS ?>/foundation.css ">
<link rel="stylesheet" href=" <?php echo $STYLE_PATH_JS_VENDOR ?>/modernizr.js ">
```

body.blade.php

```
<script src="styleFolder/foundation/js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="styleFolder/foundation/js/foundation.min.js"></script>
```

Until then, it works fine. Then I hope to simplify one more time: replace the duplicate path by global variable. So,

variables_G.blade.php

```
<?php  $STYLE_PATH_CSS="styleFolder/foundation/css" ?>
<?php  $STYLE_PATH_JS="styleFolder/foundation/js" ?>
<?php  $STYLE_PATH_JS_VENDOR="styleFolder/foundation/js/vendor" ?>
```

and new head.blade.php

```
@include('variables_G.blade.php')
<link rel="stylesheet" href=" <?php echo $STYLE_PATH_CSS ?>/normalize.css ">
<link rel="stylesheet" href=" <?php echo $STYLE_PATH_CSS ?>/foundation.css ">
<link rel="stylesheet" href=" <?php echo $STYLE_PATH_JS_VENDOR ?>/modernizr.js ">
```

then it can't find variables' value. Error message:

```
Undefined variable: STYLE_PATH_CSS.
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: The best practice would be to define variables in your controllers and pass it to the view...
Just keep it simple and conventional...
Making your app more complicated will result in issues for you in future

Comment: Just try to reimagine your app code... 'Cause indeed you got hundreds of solutions with Laravel

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Views are supposed to be dumb, this means also that you should not create variables inside of one to give to another, you should not give too much resposibility to a view.

The best way to provide global variables to Blade Views and make sure they will be available at any time is using `View::share()`:

```
View::share('STYLE_PATH_CSS', 'styleFolder/foundation/css');
View::share('STYLE_PATH_JS', 'styleFolder/foundation/js');
View::share('STYLE_PATH_JS_VENDOR', 'styleFolder/foundation/js/vendor');
```

You can add this to a composers.php file and load it in your `app/start/global.php`:

```
require app_path().'/composers.php';
```

Take a look at the docs: http://laravel.com/docs/responses#views

Comment: It works perfectly, that's amazing!! shame on me that I should've better use the official doc. Thanks!!

Comment: +1 for explaining how to include it in a separate file

Answer (score 7):

`View::share();` is the best way to make a global variable.

```
View::share('name', 'Steve');
```

To make sure a certain variable is included every time a certain view is rendered, I like [**View Composers**](http://laravel.com/docs/responses#view-composers)

You can include stuff when certain views are rendered. I suppose you could use it on your master layout(s), to make things *almost* global. It gives more control, which would be good if you need something widely available, but if it is sensitive and you don't want it everywhere.

```
View::composer('profile', function($view)
{
    $view->with('count', User::count());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

View::share('name', 'value');
easiest way to define global variable